# Can I dynamically populate array property in object during construction in c# cSharp

Tags: c#, arrays

In C#, during the initialisation of an object, developers have the ability to specify property values without using specific constructor signatures, and I'd like to know if its possible to populate an array property with a dynamic number of entries using a foreach loop (or some other dynamic looping method).

for instance...

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string[] ArrayOfItems { get; set; }
    public MyObject()
    {

    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public Item()
    {

    }
}

public void CreateNewMyObject()
{
    //List would normally come from elsewhere...
    List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item() { ItemName = "Item One" },
        new Item() { ItemName = "Item Two" },
        new Item() { ItemName = "Item Three" }
    };

    MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
    {
        ArrayOfItems = new string[]
        {
            //  This is where I'm stuck.
            //  I want to dynamically build my array but cant use foreach?
            foreach (Item item in ItemList)
            {
                item.ItemName
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what are you asking. you want to build `ArrayOfItems` based on `ItemList`?

Comment: @AmirOveisi He wants every `item.ItemName` from `ItemList` inside the `ArrayOfItems`

Comment: But why would you want to create a new list when you already got one with all items?

Comment: We're working with a set of classes as defined by the cXML standard and we need to create our own objects from the cXML sent to us to a set of web services in Microsoft Dynamics NAV. These classes haven't been built or designed by us, but we need to work with them. We're just writing the transformation code in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ like this:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
{
    ArrayOfItems = ItemList.Select(i => i.ItemName).ToArray()
}
```

If `ArrayOfItems` were of a complex type, e.g. `MyArrayItem`, and `Item` had an extra `ItemCost` property, you'd do:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
{
    ArrayOfItems = ItemList.Select(i => new MyArrayItem() { Name = i.ItemName, Cost = i.ItemCost }).ToArray()
}
```

And should `MyArrayItem` had a matching constructor:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
{
    ArrayOfItems = ItemList.Select(i => new MyArrayItem(i.ItemName, i.ItemCost)).ToArray()
}
```

Comment: Suppose we had a second property in Item, Such as "ItemCost" maybe? How could I pass that in if the ArrayOfItems was a complex type?

Comment: @Karl Create that complex type in `Select()`.

Comment: Excellent!! Exactly the answer I needed.
Thanks for your help Ondrej!!